# No WiFi Android Emulator Mac M1

Tags: android, emulator

I'm trying to get the Android Emulator to connect to Wifi on an M1 Mac. I'm using the Android S - arm64 image. The emulator starts and runs fine, but I am unable to get WiFi to turn on and stay on. If I turn on the switch in the image below in turns on, but doesn't connect to WiFi and immediately turns back off when I leave this page.

I can actually get the Experimental Android Emulator that was available for M1 Macs early on and it works fine and connects to the network. I just can't get the "official" S image to connect to any network (WiFi or Cellular). I've tried this with various hardware and with/without google play images. No change.

Any ideas on what I can try?

[AVD Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QogBw.png)

[Emulator View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViVYQ.png)

Comment: The Wifi/cellular networks inside the emulator are not real. Therefore you don't need Wifi inside the emulator. Just use the standard virtual cellular network that allows the emulator to use the network of your Mac host system.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have no connection at all, cellular or WiFi. On the “old” emulator, it used “AndroidWifi” as the emulated WiFi, and that entry does exist, but it just won’t turn on. So, no cellular and no WiFi.

Comment: May that is the effect of the beta version you use. Android S alias 12 is still beta.

Comment: That would be interesting. It’s the only option for arm images that run on M1, and the original beta emulator works fine.